# NSPredicate filtering an array of arrays using another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I want to filter an array of arrays using another array which is a subset of these arrays.

```
   NSMutableArray* y = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B", nil];

    NSArray *array = @[
                           @[@"A", @"B", @"C"],
                           @[@"A", @"B", @"E"],
                           @[@"A", @"B", @"D"],
                           @[@"B", @"C", @"D"],
                      ];
```

I want to filter the second array such that it contains the items which has both "A" and "B" in it.

I used the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *intersectPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF IN %@", y];
NSArray *intersect = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:intersectPredicate];
```

But this gives me all the items in second Array. I think ANY/SOME is considering (A || B) I want to have (A && B). I tried ALL but it gives nothing.

Comment: Well, it's really only considering the y array in this case because that's the search term you've given the NSPredicate for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Any/Some** would give all the arrays which contain either A or B.

**All** would give all the arrays which have just 2 elements A & B.

By defining a custom predicate we can get the desired results:

```
NSPredicate *intersectPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    for (NSString *str in y) {
        if (![evaluatedObject containsObject:str]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}];
NSArray *intersect = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:intersectPredicate];
```